# Programming - Principles and Practice Using C++ (2nd Edition) example not working as intended

Tags: c++

According to "Programming - Principles and Practice Using C++ (2nd Edition)" this main function:

```
int main() {
    double val = 0;
    while (std::cin) {
        std::cout << "> ";
        Token t = ts.get();
        if (t.kind == 'q') break;
        if (t.kind == ';') {
            std::cout << "= " << val << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            ts.putback(t);
        }
        val = expression();
    }
}
```

should have output as follows:

```
> 2+3;
= 5
> 3+4;
= 7
> ...etc.
```

I'm curious, how is it even possible from this code?

What I get, is:

```
> 2+3;
> = 5
> 3+4;
> = 7
> ...etc.
```

The program itself has a very convoluted logic of multiple `std::cin`s.

But I know this is a very respected book from a very respected author, so I doubt there could be a typo in it?

I'm just curious how in theory the first input could be achieved with the provided piece of code?

The `ts.get()` reads exactly one symbol from the command line. The `Token` is a single symbol read from the commmand line wrapped into a certain data structure.

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: std::cout << "> "; always prints it out. remove the std::cout << "> "; and add it inside the else{ std::cout << "> "; ts.putback(t); that way if it hits the if condition it'll print the = and else would print >

Comment: @Vasil Kuzmin I have not understood the question. There is code of the program, What does prevent you to follow the code flow step by step?

Comment: Is there anything about it in the errata?  http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2errata.html

Comment: I don't see how you could be getting another `>` output.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI You say "always", but "always" here means "before each prompt". There is not a prompt per line in the shown output.

Comment: you have a while(std::cin) while the buffer is not flushed it will constantly go through all the characters

Comment: @OmidCompSCI That's nonsense. Characters will only be delivered to the program once each.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings, try the solution I mentioned and see if that works then. Move the std::cout > to the else

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I have indeed followed it step-by-step and got the results different from the book, That's why it bothers me :)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings The `std::cout << "= "` goes BEFORE the actual value is calculated. That's why it is so strange. To even print `= *number*` I have to enter the loop again and stumble upon `std::cout << "= "`.

Comment: @VasilKuzmin Sorry, I'm not following you.